# Check if the web3 provider supports certain rpc call

Tags: web3-providers

For example, when I am using:

```
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
                method: "eth_signTypedData_v3",
                params: [customerAddress, data],
                from: customerAddress,
                id: new Date().getTime()
        }
```

I would like to know if eth_signTypedData_v3 is supported by the web3 provider before I invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know [JSON RPC 2.0](https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) has no introspection mechanisms and in Ethereum's JSON RPC specification is also no function for introspection available. Hence, the only solution that I see, is to make for every function that you want to check a request with an invalid (e.g. empty) params list.

If you get an error response with the message "Method xxxx is not supported" then you know it's not supported.

Comment: Pity, it looks like that's the case then!